# Given wrong POS machine receipt, should I be worried?

Tags: banking, debit-card, receipt, vietnam

I was shopping today and paid with a local bank debit card (not Visa, MasterCard or some international card, just an ATM card issued by a local bank). Normally there would be 3 identical receipts and I would have to sign 2 receipts, one for the retailer (let's just call it the R), one for the bank (the B). The third receipt (the C) is for the customer, i.e. me, and is not necessarily signed.

So, the situation is: I only signed the R receipt and was given the B receipt (instead of the C receipt as it should be). That is due to the mistake of the new and maybe inexperienced checkout clerk. I was not paying attention either and found out about it at home. Anyway, money was deducted from my bank account already and I have the log of the transaction in the bank's online banking app.

My question is, would I have any issues and hassles later with the "incident" today? More specifically, would I be asked to pay again or deducted from my bank account a second time? I'm definitely confident that this was not my fault to get the wrong receipt. Sorry if this might sound naïve and silly cause I don't have a lot of knowledge and experience about finance.

Comment: I don't know about Vietnam, but the larger part of the rest of the world has only two copies; and if neither you nor the merchant have a complaint, nobody would even look at the papers anymore. If it would have been me, I wouldn't even think about it.

Comment: @Aganju Yes, I admit I'm a bit paranoid about this issue since I don't know how significant the bills are, especially if auditing came to play and they would find the "missing" transaction. But then again, maybe it's just over-worrying, hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a similar system in Australia, and I’m using that as a basis to answer your question.

There are 3 relationships involved in the transaction:

1. Bank and retailer - your R receipt is the retailer’s proof that you authorised the card transaction.
2. Retailer and you - your C receipt is your proof of purchase.
3. Bank and you - your B receipt (duplicate of R) allows you to check that what you authorised (for R) is what you intended to authorise.

Since you didn’t express concern about the purchase itself (refund, return, warranty, etc), C is irrelevant. This is often the case where the purchase is not retained as-bought for a long period - e.g. restaurant meals, fuel, etc. This receipt is typically generated by the shop’s own till without reference to third parties such as banks, so if you really want the receipt, you can try going back and asking for it. The shop might have a copy for its own records, but not all retailers have their accounts set up to easily retrieve old receipts.

Since you have B, you can reconcile the transaction against your bank statement.

None of the receipts protects you from crooks who swipe your card twice and give you just one B receipt. But if the system you use requires signatures (as you note) or PIN codes for every transaction, that’s a line of defence for you in case the transaction shows up twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked my account and it was correctly deducted with the right amount as shown on the bill. About the authorizations, yes, every time they swipe my card I need PIN (since it's an ATM debit) and also 2 signatures so I think it's pretty safe to say they won't be able to deduct from my account again without my confirmation.